# Grails + Apache Shiro plugin - Setting session timeout

Tags: grails, shiro

I am working on a grails project that leverages the apache shiro plugin.  I would like to override the default session timeout.  What would be the best way to do this?  I read somewhere that you can set :

```
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout
```

Where do I set this?  In the Config.groovy file?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I found a solution : SecurityUtils.subject.getSession().setTimeout()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution works per-session, but it makes more sense to override it once in web.xml rather than overriding the default for every session. To do that, run `grails install-templates` and edit `src/templates/war/web.xml`. There's probably already a `session-config` element there, but if not you can add one:

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

To avoid upgrade issues, delete the other template files if you don't plan on changing those. You can always re-run `install-templates` since it will detect existing files and ask you whether to overwrite.

Comment: Be aware that afaik, this setting is transfered to the application server the first time you install your app. When you redeploy it, this setting is ignored and has to be changed directly in the server. At least, that's how I remeber it for tomcat...

Comment: I can't imagine a bug like that would last long. web.xml is the deployment descriptor for the archive, and its values are used during deployment whether its a new deploy or redeploy.

Comment: Hm. Didn't see it as a bug, but will recheck it... Could it be that most people redeploy by restarting the tomcat? I think in this case, the web.xml will be re-fetched from the application. But I will check to be sure...

Comment: hm. can't reproduce it, so just ignore my previous comments :-(